# How can I customize the ASP grid view column display format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my application I have following ASP grid:

```xml
<asp:datagrid id="grdMaterial" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
    PageSize="4" onselectedindexchanged="grdMaterial_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <SelectedItemStyle CssClass="CTC_Grid_SelectedItem"></SelectedItemStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Material Category">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.MATERIAL_CATEGORY") %>' CommandName="Select">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MATERIAL_QTY" HeaderText="Quantity">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
        </asp:BoundColumn>
        
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Mode="NumericPages" PageButtonCount="5"></PagerStyle>
</asp:datagrid>
```

In there, Quantity column's values are showing like this:

```
+----------+
| Quantity |
+----------+
| 89.124   |
+----------+
| 89.19    |
+----------+
| 89.1     |
+----------+
| 89       |
+----------+
| 89.56    |
+----------+
```

I need to change its format into

```
+----------+
| Quantity |
+----------+
| 89.1240  |
+----------+
| 89.19    |
+----------+
| 89.10    |
+----------+
| 89       |
+----------+
| 89.56    |
+----------+
```

So, I tried `BoundField.DataFormatString` property like this,

```xml
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="MATERIAL_QTY" HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" DataFormatString="{0:0.####;-0.####;''}"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

and this,

```xml
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="MATERIAL_QTY" HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" DataFormatString="{0:0.####0;0.##;0}"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

But it didn't work. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

It not clear in your example formatting, if you looking ALWAYS for 4 digits after the decimal.

Seems to me, that if you going to "possible" have 4 digits after the decimal point, then you ALWAYS want to display that, else the numbers are rather difficult to read.

And furthermore, you probably want the numbers to be right justified, and again, for ease of reading.

I have this gv markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" width="45%"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Width="64"
                    OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Taxes" HeaderText="Tax"  ItemStyle-Width="90px"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
            DataFormatString="{0:#.0000}"
            />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note my last column. I right justify the content, and set the format to fixed 4 decimal values. The result is this:

[image]